# Where in the database does Umbraco store its version information?

Tags: umbraco

As the title asks, Where in the database does Umbraco store its version information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its stored in the web.config file (umbracoConfigurationStatus setting) not in the database.

Richard

Comment: How then, does Umbraco know when an upgrade of the DB Schema is required?

Comment: This is not the answer to the question the original poster asked.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * FROM umbracoMigration
```

On my Umbraco gives me:

```
id  name    version createDate
1   Umbraco 7.4.1   2016-03-21 09:06:05.770
```

Comment: This is the actually answer to the question.

Comment: This only appears when you've done a migration though, I believe.. ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So if you want to check what version your current version of umbraco is look  here and you will see the latest entry

Comment: But if you've just installed Umbraco, and not yet upgraded, it will be empty, right? :(

Comment: Apparently not, mine includes the version that was installed first.

Answer (score 0):

Compares the version number in the web.config with the version being installed?